# Is there any way of plotting several categorical variables against one numerical variable in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, categorical-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
categorical_1    categorical_2    categorical_3 ... dummy
A                YY               DDDE              0   
A                ZZ               EEFG              0    
B                ZZ               DDDE              1    
C                YY               DDDE              1    
A                XX               EEFG              0    
.
.
.
```

I want to make plots of the average of the column dummy in the y-axis and the categories in the x-axis. Usually, I would do something like this:

```
df.groupby("categorical_1")["dummy"].mean().plot(kind="bar")
```

However, there are too many columns and I don't know how to do that for all of them. Is there an easy way of doing this?

I know that for numeric variables we could do something like this:

```
#scatterplot
sns.set()
cols = ['column1', 'column2',...,'columnn']
sns.pairplot(df[cols], size = 2.5)
```

But I'm not sure what to do with categorical variables

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities that I can think of.

First, you can use seaborn, but you have to change the format of you dataframe. The problem with this solution is that all hue-levels appear at each x-level.

```
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['dummy'], value_vars=cols)
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(data=df2, x='variable', y='dummy', hue='value')
```

[image]

Or, you can stick with pandas, and iterate through the columns, but then it'll be easier to create one subplot per column:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('categorical')]
target_col = 'dummy'
height = 2
width = 2
n_cols = len(cols)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,n_cols, figsize=(n_cols*width,height), gridspec_kw={'wspace':0}, sharey=True)

for col,ax in zip(cols,axs):
    df.groupby(col)[target_col].mean().plot(kind="bar", ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]